# securing outward-facing website db configs

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm adding some database usage to a public facing site, and I wanted input on what the most secure way to store mysql connection information might be. I've come up with a few options:

First I could store the config in another directory, and just set the PHP include path to look for that dir.
Second, I know there are some files that apache won't serve to browsers, I could use one of these types of files.
Third, I could store encrypted files on the server, and decrypt them with PHP.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: encryption / decryption wouldnt add alot of value since all your salts and encryption menthods would be in an executable/potentially vulenerable file anyways right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure apache to disallow any files with htaccess.

in the config folder add a `.htaccess` with the following

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

If you don't want to use .htaccess as @johua k, mentions, instead add

```
<Directory /home/www/public/config>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Directory>
```

to your apache config.

This will deny any files in that folder from being served to anyone, which is fine since php doesn't care about htaccess you can just

`include('config/db.php')`

If you properly config your php scripts, they should never appear  in plain text.

so a file like

```
define('mysql_password', 'pass')
```

would never display that text.

If you are worried about a shared hosting environment and another use having access to read this file then you should evaluate the security of the linux installation and the host. Other users should have any browsing access to your file. From the web files marked php should never return source.

You can explicitly tell apache not to serve the files ever, so they would only be include() or require() able.

Comment: I'm wary of ever actually hardcoding in a password into a script. Maybe that's illogical.

Comment: where would you put it? i mean security varies from cases to case. First i guess you should identify why / what you would be vulnerable too if you did store plain text passwords in file. The most obvious attack would be reading the source of such a file since most requests will proccess the request and run it as code, not display its contents

Comment: @user2088781 If someone accessed the encrypted password from a file they would also have access to the code to decrypt it. So it's not fool-proof.

Comment: -1. `.htaccess` files are unreliable, insecure, performance-killing abominations. Don't rely on them for security.

Comment: @JoshuaK, using the apache config makes much more sense, it boggles my mind that I didn't think of it earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Storing the config outside of apache's document root is a must

Comment: is it? i mean drupal and wordpress both store them in the document root. I mean its a good practice, but what kinds of attacks are vulnerable to this? I think having a secure stack and writing secure code is more important......

Comment: @j_mcnally Just an example. If you edit your config file with an editor that generates backup files with fancy extensions, this files may be available for any visitor. e.g. config.php~ would be downloadable for anyone.

Comment: very true.... a very valid point. I wouldn't use such a tool or upload such a file but for some a concern. In that case you could still have a config folder but deny the whole folder with htaccess.

Comment: pretty much where solid deployment tools like 'capistrano' and git '.gitignore' come in handy.